# MPMoviePlayer Won't Show When Playing Multiple Videos

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, the user can select a video from the camera roll and play within the app.  When I first select a video, everything is fine.  However, when the video ends and I go to select another video, I can hear the audio, but the video controller never shows on the screen.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [self Play];

}


-(void)Play
{


    self.player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:self.videoURL];


    self.player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    self.player.allowsAirPlay = YES;



    self.player.view.frame = self.view.frame;


    [self.view addSubview: self.player.view];
    [self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:self.player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:self.player];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.player];


    [self.player play];

}
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    NSLog(@"MovieDone");

    [self.player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:self.player];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}

- (void) exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    NSLog(@"MovieDone");
    [self.player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
     object:self.player];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening to your other self.player when you make a new one?

It is just staying there and keep a firm grasp on your resources.  Setting a new value for self.player doesn't get rid of the existing player.  You have references to it all over the place with your notifications.

You should kill all of your observers before starting a new player.  Like this:

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    NSLog(@"MovieDone");

    [self.player.view removeFromSuperview];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];//kill all the observers here

    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```